# Customize Background color for ScrollBar in Windows Store Apps

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, scrollbar, winrt-xaml

I have been trying to customize the Background color of ScrollBar in Windows Stores Apps. But its not working. I have a doubt whether is it a limitation in WinRT?

Thanks in Advance.

My Code Snippet:

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the Background color of the ScrollBar, you need to change the default style of the Scrollbar and the Blend for Visual Studio can help you implement it very easily.

For how to changing the style of the Scrollbar, please first please right-click the Scrollbar control-->click "Edit Template"-->"Edit a Copy", after that you will see all the style which creates the Scrollbar, then please find the following xaml and **change the "Fill" property of the "Rectangle" with the Background color which you want**, in this way it will change the Background color of the ScrollBar:

```
<Rectangle Fill="Yellow" Margin="0" Grid.RowSpan="5" Stroke="{ThemeResource ScrollBarTrackBorderThemeBrush}" StrokeThickness="{ThemeResource ScrollBarTrackBorderThemeThickness}"/>
```